# Increment Date from Datepicker Object C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have 2 datapicker objects I'm using to filter a Access query with.  When I run the query for example 9/1/2012 (startdate) and 9/5/2012(enddate) it gives me everything from 12am 9/1/2012 to 11:59 9/4/2012.  Is there any way to include the actual calendar day of the end day by say incrementing enddate?

Here is my code:

```
        string startDate = dateTimePicker1.Text;
        string endDate = dateTimePicker2.Text;

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startDate); 
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", endDate); 
        try {
            command.Connection = connect;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT RecordID, TimeStamp, EmployeeName, AreaDescription FROM LoginRecords r, Employees e, Areas a WHERE (e.EmployeeID = r.EmployeeID) AND (a.AreaID = r.AreaID) AND (TimeStamp BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) ORDER BY TimeStamp";
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                tw.WriteLine(reader["RecordID"].ToString() + " " + reader["TimeStamp"].ToString() + " " + reader["EmployeeName"].ToString() + " " + reader["AreaDescription"].ToString() + ",");
                listBox1.Items.Add(reader["RecordID"].ToString() + " " + reader["TimeStamp"].ToString() + " " + reader["EmployeeName"].ToString() + " " + reader["AreaDescription"].ToString() + ",");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the actual DateTime value by using the `Value` property of the `DateTimePicker`.  You can then use `AddMinutes, AddDays`, etc to increment the value.

The following will use the next day as the end date.

```
DateTime endDate = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: For reasons I can't fathom...this ended up working.
            DateTime endDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;

            string startDate = dateTimePicker1.Text;

Comment: You should not be using the DateTime value as a string.  The sql server may be running in a different culture than the application and may not recognize the formatted string.  Also use the `dateTimePicker.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can format value custom. Use following.

```
dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd";
```

If you want to use `SQL` query ,you had better to format `Date` value, like this:

```
CONVERT(varchar(10) ,dateTimePicker2.text,120)
```

Comment: the datepicker1.toString() worked just fine at first.  But it was merely omitting the endDate from the BETWEEN date1 AND date2.  I'll try and figure it out later, exactly why it did this but it did work before it just would've require specifying instructions to the user, which I had having to do.

Comment: Sorry ,I am not understand your meanig

Comment: what I meant was if I had two dates startDate and endDate...it was including the startDate all the way up to the day before the endDate.  But after changing the endDate to endDate = datepicker.value; now it includes the endDate just fine.  But that's a rather non-intuitive way of doing it.  I didn't want to have to write up docs that explain if you want date x through date y you have to make date y one day later so that you can include that date.  I hope that explains it better.